# Samsung 860 pro / evo - do they report deterministic trim?

Tags: linux, ssd, trim

Regardless of the kind - DRAT or RZAT. While all the modern ssds should behave in RZAT fashion, quite a few of them don't bother reporting such feature. And some controllers (in my case - old LSI2308 in IT mode) are sensitive in this regard.

In the past, 840 pro reported the feature just fine, 850 pro for whatever reason didn't. Evo line - afaik - never did (even if technically it was(?) supported since at least 850, but I'm not sure).

Thus my question regarding 860 series, as I haven't had any of those under my hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Samsung 860 EVO (mSATA)](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-860-evo-msata-1tb-mz-m6e1t0bw/) specs retrieved by `hdparm  -I /dev/sda`:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       Samsung SSD 860 EVO mSATA 500GB         
    Serial Number:      S41NNW0K814351T     
    Firmware Revision:  RVT41B6Q
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
....
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
```